# Submit action not running after Javascript event "OnChange" is completed

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, razor, client-side

I have a TextBoxFor in my code that looks like:

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Id, (object)new { Name = "txtID", @Onchange = "onchangeevent();", @onfocusin = "onfocusin();", @Class = "form-control" })
```

And "onchangeevent" Javascript function looks like this:

```
 function onchangeevent(){   
    if(!window.confirm("Warning: Once you edit, you cannot undo. Do you still wish to edit?")){
        $('input[name=txtID]').val('0');
    }}
```

And the submit button:

```
<input type="submit" name="submitButton" value="Submit" />
```

I was hoping to do is this:

1. User changes "txtID" value.
2. Clicks on the "submit" button without clicking somewhere else to lose focus.
3. The application displays the confirmation box to the user saying  "... you cannot undo..."
4. If the user clicks "OK", the application proceeds submitting the form. If clicks "Cancel", abort the operation.

However, this is what is actually happening:

1. User changes "txtID" value.
2. Clicks on the "submit" button without clicking somewhere else to lose focus.
3. The application displays the confirmation box to the user saying  "... you cannot undo..."
4. If the user clicks "OK", the application does NOT proceed to submit the form and it doesn't do anything.

My guess is that by pressing the submit button, the application will "lose focus" and trigger "OnChange" client-side Javascript function. However, the submit button click action is lost for some reason. Is there a way to continue submit button click if the user clicks "OK"?

Comment: I would try to avoid making the assumption the user won't click elsewhere and change the current focus.

Comment: You've got the valid point @sm1215, which I forgot to mention above. This problem shouldn't just be focusing on the submit button. The application should continue to process whatever the user clicks after pressing "OK". I just used submit button as an example.